# How to create "list of pairs" from an even-length list in python?

Tags: python, list, numpy, loops, tuples

I have a list like this, with an even number of elements:

```py
straight_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

There are six items in this list. I'd like to group them into **three pairs**, like this:

```py
paired_list = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

What's the best way to do this? More generally, given a list with `2*n` items, what's the best way to create a list of `n` pairs? I have come up with the following:

```py
straight_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
paired_list = []

for i in range(len(straight_list)//2):
    j = i*2
    pair = (straight_list[j], straight_list[j+1])
    paired_list.append(pair)
    
print(paired_list)

# [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

I also can make it work like this, though it's a tongue-twister:

```py
[tuple(x) for x in list(np.array(straight_list).reshape(len(straight_list)//2,2))]
# [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Is there a more elegant, functional, and/or "Pythonic" way to create this list of pairs?

(In some ways, this is almost an inverse of this question: ["How to make a flat list out of a list of lists?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a simple list comprehension?

`paired_list = [(straight_list[i], straight_list[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(straight_list), 2)]`

Comment: zip(straight_list[:-1:2], straight_list [1::2]) is working fine also